# Can a metro app open the default browser without opening a page?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

On button click I want to open the default metro browser (usually IE) without opening a new tab/page, just open the browser, If it is already running then just switch to it as it is to it's current state. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Where would you initiate the command to open the browser from? As a system command, I can execute `firefox about:blank`, for e.g., and that will open a new empty window/tab. I assume there's something similar for IE.

Comment: May I ask why you want to open the browser to nothing? Given the answer below I'd just send it to a blank html page. It'll accomplish the same thing right?

Comment: @MarcellFülöp I want to initiate the command from a Windows 8 Store App (Metro App) using JavaScript.

Comment: @FrankB I created a desktop app that listens to the browser and on URL change it pops a toast message, and on toast click it opens the metro app, and in the metro app I want to add a button to return to the browser. **tl;dr** - I just want a button that opens the browser as is.

Comment: I don't know Metro, but it depends on whether the JS API for Metro apps allows for system calls.

Comment: @benkol Based on what you've said I'd say look at Chue's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just something to try, and may or may not work in your scenario:

If you know the url that is open in the browser, your Windows Store app could launch that same url with the launcher.

In my app, when I launch the same url multiple times, IE will pop up but will not load a second instance of the url.

Answer (score 2):

No.  The only way to launch the browser is indirectly through the [Launcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcher.aspx).  The Launcher requires a Uri or a File and it will open the default program associated with that Uri or file type.  If it is http, for example, it will launch the default browser.  Unfortunately, it seems that the [Uri class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br225998.aspx) does not properly parse the [about Uri scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6694) nor will it accept a blank string or http address without a host.

Comment: The `about` scheme won't work for this scenario because that would open a blank page. The OP wants to switch to the browser in its current state, not open a new blank page in the browser. There is no app switch API for Windows Store apps.